# Django : dynamically added image is not showing

Tags: django

I'm making simple web page with django. I have a problem with showing image. Please help! :)

index.html : It works well.

```
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" />
```

main.js : but in javascript, It doens't work. Image is not displaying.

```
str = "<img src='{% static 'img/logo.png' %}' />"
$("#mycontent").append(str);
```

of course, `$("#mycontent").append(str);` statement works well. (but only image is not showing)

Do you have any idea with this problem?

Thank you ;)

Comment: You can't use django tags in a javascript file. the template doesn't render them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can't use django template tags in separate javascript file - they are only working within django template. So as workaround you could define variable in your template (of course within script tag)

```
var logoURL = {% static 'img/logo.png' %};
```

and then use it in your javascript file whenever you need it.